# C# - Get group info from Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD login for an app to login with Microsoft credentials and get the groups (and their info) that the user is a part of.

With this line I'm able to get the logged in user:
`var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;`

With this line I'm able to get the groups that the user is a part of:
`var groups = userClaims?.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "groups").Select(c => c.Value);`

Now I'm trying to integrate Microsoft.Graph so I can get the group's info (I only need the group's display name).

I'm using this code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
requestMessage
.Headers
.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer");
return Task.FromResult(0);}));

var group = graphClient.Groups[g].Request().GetAsync();
```

This doesn't work or I can't seem to figure out how to read properties of the group var.

Any simple way I can get the group's info?

Answer (score 0):

As per the offical [ms graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) you can fetch the group display name by below

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var groups = await graphClient.Groups
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Another work around is below:

```
var graphClient = GraphUtility.CreateGraphClient(accessToken);
var targetGroupCollection = await graphClient.Groups.Request()
                                    .Filter($"startsWith(displayName,'{groupName}')")
                                    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: The thing with the first bit of code is the authProvider. I can't figure out how to create it properly.
Also with the second one, where does the accessToken come from?

Comment: You need to be Authenticate first to get the access token.

Comment: I'm sorry but that was not helpful, if I knew how to do that I wouldn't be asking

Comment: [Web App calling Graph api](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2).This reference helps you to connect the graph API.Once you are successfully connected to graph API, you can use the above query for group display name